# How to limit the output length in Java

Tags: java, debugging, output

I have written a very basic program that takes input from the user, and then outputs it on a number of lines, with a maximum length of 16 characters per line. I first check that no single word is longer than 16 characters, then attempt to limit the output length per line. However, my code does not seem to be working when I try it with the following input:-

Input: **"There are a dozen fuzzy bunnies sleeping under the couch."**

**Expected**:

There are a

dozen fuzzy

bunnies sleeping

under the couch.

**Result**:

There are a

dozen fuzzy

bunnies sleeping

Any idea as to why my code isn't performing as expected?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Type a sentence: ");
    String originalText = keyboard.nextLine();

    String[] seperatedWords = originalText.split(" ");

    int check = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x >= seperatedWords.length; x++){
        if (seperatedWords[x].length() > 16){
            System.out.println("The input includes argumentativeness, which is longer than 16 characters.");
            check = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    String outputString = "";

    if (check == 0){
        for (int j = 0; j < seperatedWords.length; j++){
            if ((outputString + seperatedWords[j]).length() <= 16){
                outputString += seperatedWords[j] + " ";
            } else if ((outputString + seperatedWords[j]).length() >= 16){
                System.out.println(outputString);
                outputString = seperatedWords[j] + " ";
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you used your debugger to step through the code and are still stumped?

Comment: This is a misuse of SO Please try to use debugger in your favourite IDE to debug these type of issues

Answer (score 1):

You print the outputString before you update it. Also you might want to check your conditions: <= 16, >= 16 both covers == 16

```
        } else if ((outputString + seperatedWords[j]).length() >= 16){
            System.out.println(outputString);
            outputString = seperatedWords[j] + " ";
        }
```

Use 
            output += "\n" 
to add a new Line and print everything at the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, it seems the last iteration of your loop is exiting without printing the "outputString". The reason is that the length of "outputString" is less than 16, and the loops terminates while its value is "under the couch." You can add another if condition when the loop terminates to handle that :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Type a sentence: ");
    String originalText = keyboard.nextLine();

    String[] seperatedWords = originalText.split(" ");

    int check = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x >= seperatedWords.length; x++){
        if (seperatedWords[x].length() > 16){
            System.out.println("The input includes argumentativeness, which is longer than 16 characters.");
            check = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    String outputString = "";

    if (check == 0){
        for (int j = 0; j < seperatedWords.length; j++){
            if ((outputString + seperatedWords[j]).length() <= 16){
                outputString += seperatedWords[j] + " ";
            } else if ((outputString + seperatedWords[j]).length() >= 16){
                System.out.println(outputString);
                outputString = seperatedWords[j] + " ";
            }
        }
        if ( outputString.length() > 0 ){
            System.out.println(outputString);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this check never be executed:

```
for (int x = 0; x >= seperatedWords.length; x++){
```

The correct one is `x < seperatedWords.length;`

Second

```
else if ((outputString + seperatedWords[j]).length() >= 16)
```

This should be

```
else if ((outputString + seperatedWords[j]).length() > 16)
```

And you miss the last print after for loop:

```
if ( outputString.length() > 0 ){
        System.out.println(outputString);
}
```

Third, you forgot to count the space " " in your total length.